# Eureka MultipleSelectorRow

Tags: ios, filter, eureka-forms

I am doing the filter form with Eureka. So there is a list with all the the categories and also there is a "All" cell at the front. So my question is, when I press "All", how can I unselected all the other cells immediately and how can I unselect "All" when I click on other cells.

Comment: You can do so in callback .onChange

Answer (score 0):

Hope there is more elegant way exists

First remove the "All" option from your options array

Second set value for noValueDisplayText = "All"

Then put this code into .onChange callback

```
.onChange{ row in
                    if let values = row.value {
                        if values.count > 1 && values.contains("All") {
                            row.value?.remove("All")
                        }
                        else if values.count == 0 {
                            row.value = ["All"]
                        }
                    }
                }
```